# Swap functions seems to not swap?

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, uniswap

I have deployed a smart contract on a local network and I am trying to do swaps from a metamask account. I have allocated a quantity of tokens to the smart contract so it can use it using the approve function.

When calling the function I get no error and it says Transaction succeeded but the balance of USDT tokens in my Metamask doesnt change. I should be swapping USDT for USDC, but nothing seems to happen.

In summary, I want to call this function from the user's wallet, swap his USDT for USDC, and send him back the USDC.

Transaction ID: 0x5ba32142dd9b2f90ce20c992eacb16b6091b7a53833c25ad536466b747789c70

This is what I do to call the swap function in my react app:

```
await contract.methods.swapMultiHopExactAmountIn('1000', '900').send({ from: account });
```

and this is the smart contract where I swap the tokens:

```
contract spendingContract {
address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER =
    0x4A679253410272dd5232B3Ff7cF5dbB88f295319;

address private constant weth= 0xa85233C63b9Ee964Add6F2cffe00Fd84eb32338f;
address private constant usdt = 0x3Aa5ebB10DC797CAC828524e59A333d0A371443c;
address constant usdc = 0xc6e7DF5E7b4f2A278906862b61205850344D4e7d;

IUniswapV2Router private router = IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER);
IERC20 private WETH= IERC20(weth);
IERC20 private USDT = IERC20(usdt);
IERC20 private USDC = IERC20(usdc);


// Swap usdt -> weth-> usdc
function swapMultiHopExactAmountIn(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin
) external returns (uint amountOut) {
    USDT.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    USDT.approve(address(router), amountIn);

    address[] memory path;
    path = new address[](3);
    path[0] = usdt;
    path[1] = weth;
    path[2] = usdc;

    uint[] memory amounts = router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        msg.sender,
        block.timestamp
    );

    // amounts[0] = usdt amount
    // amounts[1] = weth amount
    // amounts[2] = usdc amount
    
    return amounts[2];
}
receive() external payable { }
}


interface IUniswapV2Router {
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);

function swapTokensForExactTokens(
    uint amountOut,
    uint amountInMax,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IERC20 {
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

function transferFrom(
    address sender,
    address recipient,
    uint amount
) external returns (bool);

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}
```

Comment: If you are using a local network, there is no help in stating the tx hash, because no one can access your local network. If you need to get a considerable help on this, deploy on a testnet and post the details.